# Filter the Google Finance formula to only display the "high" of all time

Tags: indexing, google-sheets, max, google-sheets-formula, google-finance

It's in reference to the Google Finance function in Google Sheets: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en

I would like to obtain the "all time LOW" (ATL) and "all time HIGH" (ATH) for a specific ticker (i.e. ABBV or GOOG) but only in 1 cell for each. Basically "What's the ATL/ATH value for this ticker?"

I've tried to do both formulas for ATL and ATH, but only ATL gives the expected result for now.

To get the ATL, you can use

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("ABBV","low","01/12/1980",TODAY(),7)
```

and to get the ATH you can use:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("ABBV","high","01/12/1980",TODAY(),7)
```

The output of this is 2 columns of data:

[image: https://imgur.com/z72pdBb]

Please note that column A, containing the timestamp, will be the one making trouble when it comes to computing the `MAX` function as it translates into some weird figures.

In order to get the ATL, I'll be using the `MIN` function which works perfectly fine:

```
=MIN(GOOGLEFINANCE("ABBV","low","01/01/1980",TODAY(),7))
```

as it will just scan the 2 columns of data and grab the lowest value which is `32.51` in USD.

BUT when I'm trying to do the same with `MAX` or `MAXA` for the ATH using for example

```
=MAX(GOOGLEFINANCE("ABBV","high","01/12/1980",TODAY(),7)
```

the result that comes out is `43616.66667` which seems to be a random computation of the column A containing the timestamp.

The expected result of the ATH should be `125.86` in USD.

I've tried using `FILTER` to excluded values >1000 but `FILTER` doesn't let me search in column B, so then I tried with `VLOOKUP` using this formula

```
 =VLOOKUP(MAX(GOOGLEFINANCE("ABBV","high","01/12/1980",TODAY(),7)),GOOGLEFINANCE("ABBV","high","01/12/1980",TODAY(),7),2,FALSE)
```

but again it returns the value of column B but based on the `MAX` value of column A which end up giving me `80.1` and not the expected `125.86`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use:

```
=MAX(INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("ABBV", "high", "01/12/1980", TODAY(), 7), , 2))
```

---

`43616.66667` is not a "random computation". it's date `31/05/2019 16:00:00` converted into a date value

`MAX` and `MIN` functions return single output from all possible cells in the included range which are in your case two columns. the date is considered as a number too so maxing out those two columns will output you the max value whenever it is from 1st or 2nd column. by introducing `INDEX` you can skip 1st column and look for a max value only in the 2nd column.

Comment: this doesnt seem to work for SOX or DJT

Comment: @mike01010 GOOGLEFINANCE is very limited on tickers - https://www.google.com/googlefinance/disclaimer/

Comment: yeah, it doesn seem to be a high priority for them. notices some issues with using 'high52' and inaccurate data as well.  a shame really...

Answer (score 0):

```
=MAX(INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("BTCSGD", "price", "01/12/1980", TODAY(), 7), , 2))
```

replace BTCSGD with any stock price you want to search up.

You can put ABCXYZ where ABC is the stock/ETF/Crypto and XYZ is the currency

Comment: Replace Max with Min to get the ATL

Comment: and change the date to find the ATL/ATH of a certain period