# How to Find Date of a stock's ATH in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, google-sheets-formula, google-finance, stockquotes

I have been trying to come up with the formula to give in 2 neighboring cells: 1.) the ALT of the stock and 2.) next the first cell, the date of the ATH value.

The example is the following:
[table structure snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kR31y.png)

I managed to address 1.) with the answer provided here - [Filter the Google Finance formula to only display the "high" of all time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56490195/filter-the-google-finance-formula-to-only-display-the-high-of-all-time)

But I am unable to define a working index formula to then give me the date when the ATH was recorded.

Thank you!

Comment: what is your formula?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=query(GOOGLEFINANCE("ABBV", "high", "01/12/1980", TODAY(), 7),"select Col2, Col1 order by Col2 desc limit 1",0)
```